# Is there a way to tell RVM to use the latest version of Ruby that is at least 2.0.0?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I often do a lot of scripting in Ruby, and sometimes I run these scripts on Jenkins jobs or put them where others can run it locally.

I would love to specify in .rvmrc something like:

- Use the most recent version of ruby that is installed
- Unless it is less then Ruby 2, in which case fail.

That way I can depend on Ruby 2 language changes (e.g., named parameters), but without forcing the environment running the script to install a new ruby if it already has 2.0.0 or 2.1.1 or 2.1.4 installed.

Comment: Did you try any ruby solution instead of .rvmrc? Usually RUBY_VERSION constant exists in all ruby environments.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run bash commands in the `.rvmrc` file. So you could check for the latest version and require it and default to a 2.0.0 version if one isn't found. I am not sure what you have in mind for failing since this file gets loaded as the terminal session is started and interrupting that would not be good.

Here is an example I crafted using `rbenv` sine I don't have `rvm` installed.

```
RV=`rbenv versions | grep -E " 2\.\d+\.\d+\S*" | grep -o -E "2\.\d+\.\d+\S*" | sort | tail -n 1`
if [[ $RV ]]
  then echo $RV
  else echo "DEFAULT"
fi
```

This example simply outputs the highest version of 2.x.x ruby it finds else it says DEFAULT. For RVM the following could work in your `.rvmrc` file although I can't test it myself. I based it on output found in the docs. You might need to adjust a little.

```
RV=`rbenv versions | grep -E "ruby-2\.\d+\.\d+\S*" | grep -o -E "2\.\d+\.\d+\S*" | sort | tail -n 1`
if [[ $RV ]]
  then rvm use $RV
  else rvm use 2.0.0
fi
```